# MySQL PDO INSERT dynamically generated query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code which works fine, as it it makes use of pdo even though the sql query is being dynamically generated (I think).

```
$fields = array(
    'col1'  => 'radiobutton1',
    'col2'  => 'radiobutton2'
);

$parts = array();

foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field){
    $parts[] = '`' . $dbfield . '` = :' . $dbfield;
}

$DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "pass" );
$DBH -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$STH = $DBH -> prepare( 'UPDATE `table1` SET ' . join(', ', $parts) . ' WHERE `id`= :id' );

$STH -> bindParam( ':id', $some_id_here, PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );

foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
    $value = isset($_POST[$field]) ? 1 : 0;
    $STH -> bindValue( ':' . $dbfield, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$STH -> execute();
```

My question is, how do I change this so it does an sql insert instead of an update?

Comment: just replace UPDATE with INSERT and remove WHERE part?

Comment: I did not know that INSERT has a SET!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
'INSERT INTO `table1` SET `id`= :id, ' . join(', ', $parts)
```

If you have an autoincrement on id:

```
'INSERT INTO `table1` SET ' . join(', ', $parts)
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that this code intended to work with checkboxes only. If you want it to work with all field types, second foreach have to be changed to

```
foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        $STH -> bindValue( ':' . $dbfield,$_POST[$field] );
    }
}
```

the rest is simple, just replace UPDATE with INSERT and remove WHERE part from the query (and obviously get rid of binding id)

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work: (I use implode() instead of join() but it's essentially the same). The reason why I use implode() instead that I think join() is confusing to use together with SQL-statements (you have to think twice whether it is SQL or it is PHP). I have not tested the code, but I hope you get the picture....

```
<?php
//...some code...
$dbValues = array();

foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
    $dbValues[] = isset($_POST[$field]) ? 1 : 0;
}

$STH = $DBH -> prepare( 'INSERT INTO `table1` (' . implode(', ', $parts) . ') VALUES(' . implode(', ', $dbValues) . ')' );

//..more code...
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a function I use for dynamic inserts using MySQL/PDO.

```
function DB_Insert($table, $data) {
    $bind = ':'.implode(',:', array_keys($data));
    $sql  = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(' . implode(',', array_keys($data)) . ') ' . 'VALUES (' .$bind. ')';
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array_combine(explode(',',$bind), array_values($data)));
}
```

$table is just a string for the table.

$data is a key/value array using the format $data['column1'] = value1

Please note, the above function does not include any data validation, I do this separately.

Comment: this code is insecure and apparently error-prone. At least you need to format your identifiers properly